# usb flash drive simulation(like cd/dvd rom virtual drive) - is it possible

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual, simulation, usb-flash-drive

is it possible to simulate usb flash drive with code (asp.net with c# is better - if not with php) or a software like virtual clone drive ?

i have a program with usb flash drive unlocker (4 my laptop) and i want to simulate that usb drive , so i can get rid of that usb flash from my laptop !

thanks in future advance

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to go into the kernel to do so. You will need to emulate a full USB root hub,  register it so that you don't mess with the real hubs, and then emulate the transactions between your flash device and your hub.

That being said, did you check that your flash drive is just a flash drive and not some kind of cryptographic token ?

Comment: thanks 4 answer / what does hub mean exactly ? -- and what do mean about cryptographic token ? -- that usb flash drive have some hidden vb code inside for unlocking the program ... / my goal for this question is learning some info about doungles and scrutiny them + is it possible to have a vitual usb like virtual cd or thses have different meanings!