# Ubuntu: emulate insert/removal of USB mass storage device

Tags: ubuntu, usb, virtual, linux-device-driver, emulation

I need a way, in Ubuntu 10.04, to simulate a USB flash drive insertion, such that the udev subsystem is notified of the insertion and can invoke rules to mount the filesystem and execute external scripts.

I've read [a detailed tutorial on how to write Linux device drivers](http://www.linuxforu.com/tag/linux-device-drivers-series/), which delves into writing [a RAMdisk](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/02/device-drivers-disk-on-ram-block-drivers/), but that virtual device doesn't have any parent device listings from udevadm, and so doesn't look like a USB device.  A post [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257422/usb-flash-drive-simulationlike-cd-dvd-rom-virtual-drive-is-it-possible) suggests that I'd have to write a virtual USB root hub.

Note that I'm not married to having a virtual USB drive tied to a RAMdisk; I'd be just as happy redirecting the virtual drive to an on-disk folder.  This will be used to Squish test the USB-centric features (insertion/removal/read/write) of an embedded application.  The application monitors the udev subsystem to figure out where it should read/write data to the removable media, and some custom rules are configured to look specifically for USB removable media, so it's important for the simulated device to look like a real USB device to udev.

Questions:
If I need to write a virtual USB root hub, could anyone point me to a tutorial to do that?
If that's not necessary, what are the next steps to extend the above-linked RAMdisk tutorial to appear as a USB mass storage device?

Thanks in advance for you responses.

Comment: Which architecture? Is this for an embedded project?

Comment: Yes, this is for an embedded project - we're using WindRiver linux on-target.  However, we use Ubuntu in a VMPlayer VM to simulate the target and host the application, and that is the environment in which we Squish test, so the solution space would actually be in 32-bit Ubuntu.